# Linking Cordova Android App To firebase #askfirebase

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, firebase, admob

I have an app which is created using Apache Cordova and Ionic. It is published on to the PlayStore with AdMob ads.

As Admob has the feature to link to firebase for better analytics I want to achieve that.

I found this video on the firebase youtube channel 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sbXF95-Qneo

The video shows how to link android AdMob apps to firebase, **But** the video is for native developers.

The build tools and process is different for web-hybrid apps such as cordova and native Android, so how can I link my hybrid app?

I found this plugin
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-firebase

But the plugin is still under development.

Kindly guide me in this regard.

Thanks.